# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function to animate text like typewriter. I can't understand why `words[index].length` is returning undefined in setInterval funcation.

```
let speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); 

function typeWriter() {
    let words = ["Achieve", "Attain"]; /* The text */ // 6

    let typeWriter = document.getElementById("typewriter");
    let i = 1;
    let index = 0;
    while (index < words.length) {

        setInterval(() => {

            if (i <= words[index].length && i > 0) {
                typeWriter.innerHTML = words[index].slice(0, i);

                if (i == words[index].length) {
                    i = -1;
                }else {
                    i++;
                }
            } else if ((i * -1) <= words[index].length && i < 0) {
                typeWriter.innerHTML = words[index].slice(0, i);

                if ((i * -1) == words[index].length) {
                    clearInterval();
                }else {
                    i--;
                }
            }

            speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

       }, speed);

       if (index == words.length) {
           index = 0;
       } else {
           index++
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: `words[index].length` is not returning undefined. Read the error message carefully. `words[index]` is undefined. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. `index` is `2` by the time any of your `setInterval` callbacks are executed. Please also see [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3583724/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with a closure on `setInterval` function.

```
while (index < words.length) {
    const word = words[index]; // fetch word from the array as a constant
    setInterval(() => {

        if (i <= word.length && i > 0) {
            typeWriter.innerHTML = word.slice(0, i); // use word reference

    ...
```

You need to fetch the value to a constant before calling `setInterval`, then use it. Because all code is inside of a single block of code, your index variable is modified before setInterval block is executed. So you need to make your `setInnterval` code execution be independent from index variable.

Second solution would be to move your setInterval to second function, that receives index as a parameter. That way, index value would be copied and not change inside of this block, even if original value will change.